# Unable to Configure Session Timeout in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, development, web-part, sharepoint-on-prem

As per the Information Security Requirement of my Organization, I am trying to configure Session timeout after 15 minutes in SharePoint 2016 On Premise Application but unable to achieve the same.

I've Tried [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/17219ec3-08e6-4b7f-a5c4-85dfdf34c8f0/session-time-out-setting-for-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointsearch) solution but it doesn't work and I don't find any possible solution to achieve the same in AD based Authentication.

Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using Windows Authentication, in effect, there is no Session Timeout. This is because Kerberos and NTLM are stateless protocols, so they do not maintain session and re-auth immediately.